# PHP + PayPal - how to integrate/merge both?

Tags: php, web-services, paypal, integration

i have an idea about how pay-pal works but not an expert.

I'm asked **to implement online banking (*using PHP*) through PAY-PAL in my page.**

I've *no idea where to begin*.

No **introductory sites** where found by 'googling'.

- Is web-service needed for this implementation?
- Any site for beginners will do.

Thanx all.

Answer (score 3):

[check out this link](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/helpweb?cmd=_help)


Read this section
**Using Merchant Services** 

You will get basic info of

Adding PayPal to my website

Website payments

Subscriptions

Email payments

Coupons

Comment: After you get a grip with how paypal payment work, you might need to use this class (http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html) to ease you getting the paypal payment page work.

Paypal have a quite complete documentation and tutorial. You might also want to create a sandbox account (https://developer.paypal.com/) to test your payment page. After you sure all working as expected, then you can use your actual paypal account to receive payment.

Comment: thanx a lot bros... i'm tryin to understand now.It may take some time than xpected since i'm new to this stuff... anyways will c :)